# MySQL Date Range

Tags: mysql, sql, database, date

I have an automated query that counts the number of searches made each week, at the moment it is showing just the month the search took place in, i would like it to show the date range of the respective week it is showing the data for, i.e 30/09/13 - 07/10/13

My query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`,
    `region`,
    MONTHNAME(`date`) as `month`
FROM stores.stats
WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE (NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK)
    AND `date` < DATE (NOW())
GROUP BY `region`,
    MONTH(`date`);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add the range to your select list, like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `count`,
    `region`,
    MONTHNAME(`date`) as `month`,
    DATE_ADD(DATE (NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK) as `range start`,
    DATE (NOW()) as `range stop`
FROM stores.stats
WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE (NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK)
    AND `date` < DATE (NOW())
GROUP BY `region`,
    MONTH(`date`)
```

Comment: Since [NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) returns a constant (time that indicates the time at which the statement began to execute), it is not necessary to have it in the group by.

Comment: Instead of having 2 columns one for start and another for finish, could i have just one column? So the result would be something like: 2013-09-30 / 2013-10-07

Comment: Absolutely! Just concatenate the values like this: `DATE_ADD(DATE (NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK) + " / " + DATE(NOW())`

Comment: Am i missing something? As im getting a weird result '40261937'      **SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,`region`, DATE_ADD(DATE (NOW()), INTERVAL - 1 WEEK) + "/" + DATE(NOW()) as `week ending` FROM stores.stats WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) AND `date` < + "/" + DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY `region`, DATE(NOW());**

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that you have to cast the date expressions on both sides of the " / " to a varchar value.